# Como manipular e submeter dados através de GET e POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, get, http-request

Tenho uma aplicação Web e preciso acessar uma url externa que possui login e senha. Posteriormente devo preencher um formulário, submeter os dados e receber o retorno na minha aplicação!

Isso é possível utilizando as requisições web http do C#(GET, POST)?

Comment: Depende de como é feita a autenticação dessa url externa, explique melhor o seu cenário, mostre o código de como está fazendo e aponte onde está encontrando o erro.

Answer (score 2):

A comunicação entre aplicações web é de fato através do HTTP, é possível sim você fazer essa comunicação através dos verbos (também conhecidos por métodos) GET e POST.

Em C# eu utilizo um framework bem bacana chamado Flurl, o link para acessa-lo é [este](https://flurl.io/). No site  tem uma vasta documentação de como utiliza-lo para vários propósitos.

Para seu caso, o login e senha possivelmente será enviado por uma requisição POST, o qual pode ser enviado por JSON.

```
await "http://site.com.br".PostJsonAsync(new { login = "blabla", senha = "teste" });
```

Para recuperar o recurso através do GET é mais simples ainda.

```
var response = await "http://site.com.br".GetJsonAsync();
```

No caso acima você recebe um object dinamicamente, porém é possível você definir o mapeamento fortemente tipado para alguma classe especifica.

```
SuaClasse obj = await "http://site.com.br".GetJsonAsync<SuaClasse>();
```

Eu utilizo bastante para consumir APIs RESTFUL e na minha opinião é muito prático.

Espero ter ajudado! :)

Comment: Opa, obrigado, vou ver a documentação!